# How to write my reverse function properly?

Tags: javascript

i have a problem and i need help for this question.

My reverse function doesn't work the way I want it to.

```js
    function reverseArrayInPlace(array){
      let old = array;
      for (let i = 0; i < old.length; i++){
       array[i] = old[old.length - 1 - i];
      };
    };

    let arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue);
    console.log(arrayValue);
```

I expect on [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] but i have [5, 4, 3, 4, 5].

Why does it work this way? Please help me understand.

P.S I know about the reverse method.

Comment: an assignment of an array does not copy the values. it take the same object reference as all non primitive types.

Comment: As Nina points out, consider making a new array, then populating that.

Comment: Oh really, I'll use a slice to copy the array

Comment: I wouldn't use `slice`. Just walk half the length and swap elements `i` and `length-i-1`. Then you have a true in-place algorithm with no extra memory and it's single-pass. Making a second array seems like a waste--you might as well just `.reverse()` if you're going to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable, with assigned object (array, which is a modified object in fact) - stores just a link to that object, but not the actual object. So, `let old = array;` here you just created a new link to the same array. Any changes with both variables will cause the change of array.

(demo)

```js
let arr = [0,0,0,0,0];

let bubu = arr;

bubu[0] = 999

console.log( arr );
```

The simplest way to create an array clone:

```js
function reverseArrayInPlace(array){
  let old = array.slice(0); // <<< 
  for (let i = 0; i < old.length; i++){
    array[i] = old[old.length - 1 - i];
  };
  
  return array;
};

console.log( reverseArrayInPlace( [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] ) );
```

P.s. just for fun:

```js
function reverseArrayInPlace(array){
  let len = array.length;
  let half = (len / 2) ^ 0; // XOR with 0 <==> Math.trunc()
  
  for( let i = 0; i < half; i++ ){
    [ array[i], array[len - i-1] ] = [ array[len - i-1], array[i] ]
  }
  
  return array;
};

console.log( reverseArrayInPlace( [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing a true [in place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm) algorithm, it's wasteful from both a speed and memory standpoint to make an unnecessary copy (as other answers point out--`array` and `old` are aliases in the original code).

A better approach is to iterate over half of the array, swapping each element with its `length - 1 - i` compliment. This has 1/4 of the iterations of the `slice` approach, is more intuitive and uses constant time memory.

```js
const reverseArrayInPlace = a => {
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length / 2; i++) {
    [a[i], a[a.length-1-i]] = [a[a.length-1-i], a[i]];
  }
};

const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
reverseArrayInPlace(a);
console.log(a);
```

Since this is a hot loop, making two array objects on the heap just to toss them out is inefficient, so if you're not transpiling this, you might want to use a traditional swap with a temporary variable.

```js
function reverseArrayInPlace(a) {
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length / 2; i++) {
    var temp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[a.length-i-1];
    a[a.length-i-1] = temp;
  }
};

var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
reverseArrayInPlace(a);
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have in `old` variable the same array (not by value, but by reference), so if you change any of them you'll have changes in both.

So you should create new array, make whatever you want with them and return it (or just copy values back to your origin array if you don't want to return anything from your function).

It happend like that because:

1) `arr[0] = arr[4]` (5,2,3,4,5)

2) `arr[1] = arr[3]` (5,4,3,4,5)

....

n) `arr[n] = arr[0]` (5,4,3,4,5)

So you can just make a copy (`let old  = array.slice()`) and it'll be woking as you'd expect.